# C# linq query data table take method

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I'm not able to call take method from below linq query

```
var data = from tb in table.AsEnumerable()
           join ch in channelTable.AsEnumerable() on syskey equals (DateTime)ch["syskey"]
           orderby Convert.ToDouble(tb[(string.Format("Channel{0}_data",Convert.ToInt32(ch["Channel_No"])))]) descending                       
           select new
           {
               Channel_No = ch["Channel_No"],
               Channel_data = tb[string.Format("Channel{0}_data", Convert.ToInt32(ch["Channel_No"]))],
           };
```

How can I add Take(5) from above linq query?

Comment: You can use [`let`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) to clean the query a little, and avoid duplication of this ugliness: `tb[(string.Format("Channel{0}_data",Convert.ToInt32(ch["Channel_No"])))]`

Comment: the table is dynamically generate that's why i created query as above with string format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As simply as:

```
var top5 = data.Take(5);
```

You *can* do it in the same statement, too, but it's a bit ugly:

```
var data = (from tb in table.AsEnumerable()
            join ch in channelTable.AsEnumerable() on syskey equals (DateTime)ch["syskey"]
            orderby Convert.ToDouble(tb[(string.Format("Channel{0}_data",Convert.ToInt32(ch["Channel_No"])))]) descending                       
            select new
            {
                Channel_No = ch["Channel_No"],
                Channel_data = tb[string.Format("Channel{0}_data", Convert.ToInt32(ch["Channel_No"]))],
            }).Take(5);
```

Note that ordering by a *string* here probably doesn't do what you want, unless your values are all single digit - would you really want channel3, channel2, channel10, channel1?

It's a pretty odd query though - especially as your join doesn't use anything from the first table...

Comment: But i want Take(5) from each channel?

Comment: @nag: It's not clear what you mean, or how your data is structured, or why you've got a join which doesn't use the left side of it, or why you end up using the value of a column as part of the *column name* of another table (ick). I'm afraid without more clarity, I can't help you any further.

Comment: I'll get final result as channelNo 11111122223335445444 and data 230,0.23,9,0.564 like this so from this i want take 5 from each channel

Comment: @nag: That's still *far* from clear. Please edit your question to clarify it, after reading http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: It's working but i added extra GroupBy() to before take as suggest by above.